# MapServer to PostGIS raster table DATA query too long

Tags: postgis, postgresql, wms, mapserver, wcs

I have all my rasters in one table, I would like to serve them through WMS and WCS.

I Generate the mapfile with mapscript and query the rasters with:

```
ms_layer.data = f"PG:host='{HOST}' user='{USER}' password='{PASS}' " \
                f"dbname='{DB}' schema='some_schema' table='{some_table}' " \
                f"column='rast' mode=2 where='field_id IN ({field_ids}) AND rast IS NOT NULL"
```

This works well for a short list of field ids but with a long (could be up to 10000) it won't because of the "path too long error". I assume the DATA instruction is treated as a path and os determines its max length, preventing the query to execute and the "mosaicked" raster to draw. Correct me if I'm wrong.

My temporary solution is to limit the field_ids list to the ones displayed on e.g. QGIS map display when zoomed in. But I would like to display the entire list of fields also. Plus, this approach does not work for WCS where the entire list has to be used to produce a full dataset.

Is there a solution on MapServer/SQL level or do I have to restructure my database? Any 3rd options?

Comment: Do you want one layer/coverage per raster, one layer/coverage which is a union of all rasters, or some other combo?

Comment: A mosaic of all rasters that have the field_id in the (field_ids).

Comment: My second and if I don't figure something better, the final solution is to use another layer (with connection to vector table of fields) as a mask. It works with geometry. But I would like to select rasters by ids rather than masking them.